# List obtained from Parse.com to an Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-platform, spinner

I'm trying to get an array list from parse.com and insert it into a Spinner to have more control of my app. I've seen how to add things via code to a Spinner, but I've not been able to retrieve a list from Parse and put it into the spinner.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Modelos");
        try {
            mod = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(mod.get(1).toString());
```

With the code above I'm able to get the Object as it is but I'm not able to access any attributes.
My output gets:

```
I/System.out﹕ com.parse.ParseObject@425b9c78
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can see [here](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-retrieving) to retrieve a List of ParseObject, after you have the List you only need a adapter to show the information what you like, [here](http://www.edureka.co/blog/custom-spinner-in-android/) have an example.

**EDIT**

Remember the index in java start in 0, after that if you call toString in some ParseObject you only get the string representation of any java object, because isn't implemented the toString method in ParseObject.

To access to the information retrieved in some ParseObject you need call getString, getInt, getDouble, etc.

```
Log.d("ParseObject", mod.get(0).getString("column_name"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it when I go to my workspace and I'll get back :)

Comment: Hi, I'm having a problem, I'm trying to obtain all the objects of a column "Modelo" from the database in parse as an array to put it into the List but I've tried and I can't achieve to do so. Please help.

Comment: I added it into my question what I put into it.

Comment: Oh that seems like it'd work, I'll try it tomorrow and get back at you. Another thing, how could I check for ANY available object in the list ? Like there are 3 objects stored, and I want a list of all of them inserted into the spinner, how could I do that?

Comment: You already have the objects in a List, you can access it by their index. To put all your items in a Spinner, the way it's using a adapter, specifically a custom one, in that adapter you tell it who gonna be displayed the information of each item, the second link in my answer it's how to make it.